# Log NullReferenceException whenever it's being thrown somewhere in code

Tags: c#, exception

When running application in Visual Studio there is a setting which allow debugger to break anytime some specified exception is being thrown (even if it's properly caught by the application).

This is a very useful feature because in my application some exceptions (e.g. null reference) should never occur and the programmer should write a code in a way to avoid them (e.g. always perform null-check where null could appear). Thanks to the above mentioned feature my debugger will always break directly at the place of bug when this unwanted exception occur.

Now I would like to inject the similar logic to the release code. I would like every instance of some exception be logged with a stacktrace whenever it occurs even if this exception is caught and handled in the code. Is there such a mechanism in C#?

I could obviously add `(catch NullReferenceException)` clause to all `try/catch` blocks, but this would be very tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [FirstChanceException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event on the [AppDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Comment: Also if your thing is an asp.net thing then ELMAH can log things nicely. 

https://elmah.github.io/